# BackgroundTask.define not started

Tags: react-native, background-task

### react-native-background-task

I want the code to run back in time. I'm trying to use react-native-background-task. But BackgroundTask.define does not start.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'

BackgroundTask.define(() => {
    console.log('Hello from a background task')
    BackgroundTask.finish()
})

export default  class Home extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        BackgroundTask.schedule({
            period:1
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <Text>Hello world</Text>
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

this is due to linking issue

Android

he linking of the library can be done automatically by running:

```
$ react-native link react-native-background-task
```

One manual step is still needed - 
in your project file android/app/src/main/java/myapp/MainApplication.java, add the following to the end of the onCreate() method:

```
BackgroundTaskPackage.useContext(this);
```

iOS

For iOS support, this library relies on version 2.0.x of react-native-background-fetch which can be installed as follows:

```
$ npm install react-native-background-fetch@2.0.x --save
$ react-native link react-native-background-fetch
```

This library will behave correctly on iOS as long as react-native-background-fetch is installed alongside it, and has been linked with your project.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I continue to have the same problem even though I have followed all of these steps